# jquery cookie not functioning

Tags: jquery, cookies, hash, tabs

I have the following code written and i'm using jquery cookie, but i think it isn't working. But as soon as i remove these 2 statements,

```
$.cookies(cookieName, hash, cookieOptions);

alert($.cookies(cookieName));
```

everything else works properly, are there any syntax error on them? I also checked with other browsers and i'm using localhost, none of the browser works with the cookies as well. Any help is very very much appreciated!

Regards
Jay

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a.tab").click(function () {
        var cookieName = 'active';
        var cookieOptions = {expires: 7, path: '/'};

        var hash = this.getAttribute("href");

        if (hash.substring(0, 1) === "#") {
            hash = hash.substring(1);
        }
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        location.hash = hash;

        $.cookies(cookieName, hash, cookieOptions);
        alert($.cookies(cookieName));

        alert(hash);
        showTab(hash);

        return false;
    });

    function showTab(hash) {
        $(".content").hide();
        var content_show = "content_";
        $("#"+content_show+hash).fadeIn();
    };
});
```

Comment: `<script src="/path/to/jquery.cookie.js"></script>` ? https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: Checked the console for errors?

Comment: Hi, this is the path i use
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cookies.js"></script>

pretty sure its correct cuz all the js are inside this folder and all of them are functioning except perhaps this one.